# PHP long-polling request issue

Tags: php, angular, long-polling

I am new to the Long-polling requests concept and having an issue with the requests from an Angular project to PHP XAMPP local server.
When the request time limit is set to 0 like

```php
set_time_limit(0);
```

The requests stay alive forever. Even after the client reloads the website page or closes the whole tab the request won't stop processing the script and keep repeating it.
If the client reloads the website page 10 times then closes the tab, the PHP server will keep processing 10 different requests for no one.

I am wondering how to avoid that or, how to exit the request once the client is not going to receive its response by reloading/leaving the page?

my api code:

```php
            set_time_limit(0);
            $accountId = 1;
            $database = DBManager::link();

            while (true) {

                $database->call('account_get_notifications_updates')
                    ->value('_accountId', $accountId, DBParams::INT);

                if ($database->run()) {

                    $sqlResults  = $database->fetchArray();
                    $returnValue = $database->getReturnValue();
                    
                    if ($returnValue == 0) {
                        // add the new notifications to the response and exit
                        $this->Response->SetData($sqlResults['dataSet2']);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        sleep(30);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                throw new \Exception($database->getError()->message);
            }
```

Comment: The script will terminate once it reaches its end regardless of  a `set_time_limit(0);`. ... I'm not sure if you understand this

Comment: @GetSet i do understand that, but the script is not designed to exit as long as there are no new notifications. if the user refreshed the website page angular will fire a new HTTP request while the first request still on the loop waiting for any updates from the database making a problem for having (x) requests for the same user (I've updated the code above, maybe it will explain the problem better)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP longpolling running endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268314/php-longpolling-running-endlessly)

Comment: `$tisTrue = true; while ($tisTrue) { ... $tisTrue = false; }`

Comment: @Blackhole it's exactly what i need, but that function for some reason has no effect. the script still keeps going even after closing the whole browser tab.

Comment: @JaredFarrish it won't really work because there's ``` continue; ``` command when the database returns no updates. i also can't remove that, because... what is the point of a long-polling request if it will run only one round of the loop?

Comment: Probably naively: https://3v4l.org/mKWZF

Comment: @JaredFarrish but that still means if there were no updates from the database the script will sleep for 3 sec then the whole request will exit instead of looping for another check

Comment: Sounds like you really want push notifications using a background worker and message broker. Probably look at ReactPHP and Pusher. You also won't hit the performance bottleneck that long polling will have (I think nginx can reuse a process for all requests but I've not done that).

Comment: Here is an example that allows for 10 attempts, although it doesn't solve the multiple process issue (since that's a server request issue): https://3v4l.org/D9mFG

Comment: @JaredFarrish I do want to push real-time notifications between angular and PHP Rest API but i don't know what is the best way to do it, I've seen examples of long-polling request, and all of them seem to have the same issue, which the requests will keep going even if client disconnected. So i am just confused about the whole long-polling thing now.

Comment: I would not use long polling. Instead, setup a background worker (ReactPHP) running in the background of the server (not a web process), push channels (Pusher) that your frontend registers with, then have the background worker periodically query and "announce" the messages on the channels. Your frontend app is then listening and receives those messages, with Pusher (or some other) intermediary.

Comment: http://socketo.me/

Comment: @JaredFarrish could you link me a guide or example that shows how to use them to have real-time notifications, please?

Comment: @JaredFarrish is having websocket server to just push notifications is a good idea?

Comment: Long polling is not a good idea. (Y'know, locking a single web server process for minutes at a time.)